# Force responsive image gallery to be the height of it's parent

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jasfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g79a2jw7/11/

**Setup:**

- Very basic image gallery setup, happy with this basic functionality
- Uses inline-block grid like the pure-grid because that's what the site uses
- Gallery images are inserted as an inline background style, then image is hidden
- This allows for css image size/cropping control within responsive layouts like this:

  ```
  .gallery-item {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
  }
  ```

**Problems I'm trying to solve:**

- Need the height on the `.gallery` & `.gallery-item` divs to confirm to the height of the parent `.hero` div so the gallery height always matches the hero text to the right. The css `background-size: cover;` properties should take care of the centred image cropping once the height is sorted
- Then need the prev/next buttons to calculate their vertical centering based on the height of the gallery
- Need the gallery to be in normal flow on mobile so it pushes the text below it
- Happy to go with a completely different approach if it allows for all centred image cropping etc
- Need IE 9+ support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy with jQuery:
If .hero div is immediate parent, you can use parent() -- otherwise, you can use parents() with selector

```
$('.gallery, .gallery-item').each(function(){
    var parent_height = $(this).parents('.hero').height();
    $(this).height(parent_height);
});
```

Comment: For those that know jQuery, you're right, it's way easier - thanks heaps! One last thing if you have time, how do I fix the full screen mode - click the top right arrow in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g79a2jw7/13/ I made the full screen mode by getting jQuery to add a class of ````gallery-zoomed````. So is the easiest way to to have your jQuery not execute if ````.gallery```` has the ````.gallery-zoomed```` class? Also, is there a way to have the buttons vertically centre based on the height of the image?